# Calculate man days in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one table for training sessions in MySQL database as below. I want to calculate training man days , for that i am getting values from this table (i.e) for a particular month, how many trainee and how many days they attended the training.

```
id  trainee course  category  fromdate   todate      status
1   111     sim     Pro      01-02-2015  08-04-2015  Pending
2   169     Sim     VM       01-03-2015  04-03-2015  Completed
```

So in above table, first training(abc) started in Feb 1 and ends in April 8 and second training(xyz) from march 1 to march 8.
I want to calculate as

```
for the month of February training days = 28 , No. of Trainees = 1  
March training days = 31 + 4 , No. of Trainees = 2  
April training days = 8 , No. of Trainees = 1
```

First i need to get training done in particular month.SO i used below select query

> ```
> SELECT * FROM trainingsessions where 
> fromdate between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28' and
> todate between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28' ;
> ```

But second parameter get failed and nothing returns.
How can i do that?

Comment: Hi, are the `fromdate` and `todate` fields of `date` type in the database? If so, try: SELECT * FROM trainingsessions where 
fromdate between '2015-02-01 00:00:00' and '2015-02-28 23:59:59' and
todate between '2015-02-01 00:00:00' and '2015-02-28 23:59:59' ;

Comment: i tried the same.but todate has 2015-04-01, so the second condition fails there.